# Is it convex function?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have a function and I don't know it is whether convex or non-convex:
$$J(c,\alpha)=\int_\Omega ( \alpha c-I(x))^2u \, dx+ \|\alpha\|^2$$
where $0 \le u \le 1$, $I(x): \Omega \to R$, $c$ is constant

Is it convex function?
As my knowlegde, it is convex function because $\int_\Omega ( \alpha c-I(x))^2u \, dx$ is convex function in term of $0 \le u \le 1$ and $ \|\alpha\|^2$ is also convex, then totally, $J(c,\alpha)$ is convex.

Answer (score 3):

As a function of $c$, it is convex.  As a function of $\alpha$, it is convex.  But it is not jointly convex in $\alpha$ and $c$.

Comment: @Thank Robert Israel. The second term $∥α∥^2$ is a regularization term. I need put it in $J$ function. However, as you said, it will lost convex properties of $J$. Could you suggest to me some way to make $J$ is convex

Comment: You don't "make" a function convex. (The exceptions are uncommon and specific.) Now, if you're looking for a way to *solve* the problem, you could consider an alternating projection method of sorts: minimize over $\alpha$, then over $c$, and back and forth until no further progress is made.

Comment: Good idea. That mean I will $min J$ in iteration. At fist iteration, we find the $\alpha$ by $\frac {\partial J}{\partial \alpha}=0$, and find $c$ by $\frac {\partial J}{\partial c}=0$, then compute the $J$ from $\alpha ,c$. And we do it again until $J_{t+1}-J_t<\epsilon$. Is it your said?

Comment: That's right. Look up "alternating minimization" in Google for more info.

Answer (score 1):

If $x \mapsto f(x,t)$ is convex for each $t$, and $\mu$ is a positive measure, then $x \mapsto \int f(x,t) d\mu(t)$ is convex.

It follows that convex combinations of convex functions are convex.

Hence $\alpha \to J(c,\alpha)$ is convex.

In particular, since $(\alpha,x) = ( \alpha c-I(x))^2u$ is convex for each $x$,
then $(\alpha,x) = \int_\Omega ( \alpha c-I(x))^2u dx $ is convex (using $\mu = \lambda$, the Lebesgue measure).

The function $\alpha  \mapsto \|\alpha\|^2$ is convex.

The sum of convex functions is convex.